# como puedo imprimir correctamente la media del coste en esta array de objetos?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una array de objetos y tengo que imprimir por pantalla la media del coste de los vuelos, y en vez de darme solo el resultado final, el codigo me imprime toda la operacion.

```js
let flights = [

    { id: 00, to: 'Bilbao', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 1600, scale: false },

    { id: 01, to: 'New York', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 700, scale: false },

    { id: 02, to: 'Los Angeles', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1100, scale: true },

    { id: 03, to: 'Paris', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 210, scale: false },

    { id: 04, to: 'Roma', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: false },

    { id: 05, to: 'London', from: 'Madrid', cost: 200, scale: false },

    { id: 06, to: 'Madrid', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 90, scale: false },

    { id: 07, to: 'Tokyo', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1500, scale: true },

    { id: 08, to: 'Shangai', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 800, scale: true },

    { id: 09, to: 'Sydney', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: true },

    { id: 10, to: 'Tel-Aviv', from: 'Madrid', cost: 150, scale: false } ];
    var suma = 0;


function averagePrice(){
    document.write('<h1>Precio medio de los vuelos</h1>');
    for(let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++){
       suma += flights[i].cost;
       console.log(suma/11);
       document.write('El precio medio de los vuelos es: '+ suma/11);
     }
   };
   averagePrice();
```

**EL RESULTADO:**

```
El precio medio de los vuelos es: 145.45454545454547El precio medio de los vuelos es: 209.0909090909091El precio medio de los vuelos es: 309.09090909090907El precio medio de los vuelos es: 328.1818181818182El precio medio de los vuelos es: 341.8181818181818El precio medio de los vuelos es: 360El precio medio de los vuelos es: 368.1818181818182El precio medio de los vuelos es: 504.54545454545456El precio medio de los vuelos es: 577.2727272727273El precio medio de los vuelos es: 590.9090909090909El precio medio de los vuelos es: 604.5454545454545
```

El resultado debería ser solo:

```
El precio medio de los vuelos es: 604.5454545454545.
```

Comment: Que fácil era y no lo veía, gracias Christian.

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar estas escribiendo por cada iteración, por eso te aparece el teto repetido, luego estas sacando el promedio en cada iteración y solo lo debes hacer al final. Puedes optar por un ciclo `for of` o utilizar un `forEach`.

```js
let flights = [

    { id: 00, to: 'Bilbao', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 1600, scale: false },

    { id: 01, to: 'New York', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 700, scale: false },

    { id: 02, to: 'Los Angeles', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1100, scale: true },

    { id: 03, to: 'Paris', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 210, scale: false },

    { id: 04, to: 'Roma', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: false },

    { id: 05, to: 'London', from: 'Madrid', cost: 200, scale: false },

    { id: 06, to: 'Madrid', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 90, scale: false },

    { id: 07, to: 'Tokyo', from: 'Madrid', cost: 1500, scale: true },

    { id: 08, to: 'Shangai', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 800, scale: true },

    { id: 09, to: 'Sydney', from: 'Barcelona', cost: 150, scale: true },

    { id: 10, to: 'Tel-Aviv', from: 'Madrid', cost: 150, scale: false } ];
    

function prom(array){
  let suma = 0;
  for(const dato of array){
    suma += dato.cost
  }
  return suma/array.length;
}

console.log(prom(flights))
```

Con el ciclo `for of` se recorre cada elemento del array y podemos acceder a sus índices como con un objeto json. También lo puedes hacer con un `forEach` mucho más simple.

```js
function prom2(array){
  let suma = 0;
  array.forEach(elemento => suma+= elemento.cost)
  return suma/array.length;
}
console.log(prom2(flights))
```

Answer (score 0):

No es un error lo que te sucede. Recuerda que los ciclos repiten todas las instrucciones en su interior siempre que la condición se cumpla.

Si lo que buscas es que los mensajes solo se envíen una vez, deberías mover el `console.log()` y el `document.write()` fuera del ciclo.

Una recomendación: si dejas el 11, el promedio se calculará bien solo cuando el arreglo tenga 11 elementos. Puedes reemplazarlo por `flights.length`.

El código quedaría algo así:

```
for(let i = 0; i < flights.length; i++){
    suma += flights[i].cost;
}
console.log(suma / flights.length);
document.write('El precio medio de los vuelos es: ' + suma / flights.length);
```

Comment: Una repuesta proporciona un ejemplo de la solución.

Comment: He publicado algunas respuestas sin ejemplos y nunca me han dicho nada ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: pues, para que sepas una buena respuesta brinda un ejemplo de la solución, así todo queda claro.

Comment: Ok, gracias por el consejo.